# java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

when i was trying to read data from Oracle database  using the following code i was getting exception

```
PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM TBLUSER");
pst.executeQuery();
```

But this table is actually exist in my database when i use this command directly in the command prompt its working fine.And also for one table among the tables in database this code is working fine ,but for other table names its not working properly.So someone please explain why this is happening.

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:112)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:331)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:288)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.receive(T4C8Oall.java:743)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.doOall8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:216)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeForDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:799)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(OracleStatement.java:1038)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.executeMaybeDescribe(T4CPreparedStatement.java:839)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1133)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3285)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeQuery(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3329)
        at com.symp.ControllerServlet.service(ControllerServlet.java:302)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Hmmm, what JDBC driver are you using? com.mysql.jdbc.Driver or oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver? if you are using oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver you are using a wrong driver.

Comment: Make sure the table is granted for the user that you are accessing DB from java!

Comment: @vzamanillo, It will not throw ORA-00942 exception when driver is wrong!

Comment: @hemanth, Connecting to MySQL using Oracle JDBC driver? huh?

Comment: Connection itself will not be established when the driver is wrong. As per the exception details, there is a valid connection but somehow unable to access the table.

Comment: If you get an ORA-xxxx error you are not connecting to MySQL, it is impossible, this is what I am trying to say.

Comment: yes the connection was established but i was not able to access the table..

Comment: @rajasekhar but you are not connecting to MySQL, right?

Comment: @rajasekhar  Please share the complete DB code.  So that we can determine whether you are connecting MySQL or Oracle database

Comment: @vzamanillo  thank you,the problem is i am using multiple connections in the program to login to application i have used Oracle connection.And th client will be acessed his tables present in mysql database.By mistakenly i have referred oracle connection variable and tried to acess mysql table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is i am using multiple connections in the program to login to application i have used Oracle connection which is given as class level variable.And the client will be accessed his tables present in MySQL database using MySQL connection which is service method level variable.By mistakenly i have referred oracle connection variable and tried to acess mysql table

Answer (score 1):

Check each of the following:

```
1) the spelling of the table or view name.
2) that a view is not specified where a table is required.
3) that an existing table or view name exists.
```

Contact the database administrator if the table needs to be created or if user or application privileges are required to access the table.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are using the correcte informations :

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/YOUR_SCHEMA";
Driver driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver();
String userName = "user";
String password = "pass";
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when using persist() in Hibernate and the solution was to execute:

```
grant all on <schema>.<table> to <user>;
grant all on <schema>.<sequence> to <user>;
```

Comment: Thank You @Aliuk, I searched a lot and tried many solutions but not a single one worked. I tried this it works for me.